# CLLocationCoordinate2D returns integers for latitude and longitude instead of double

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm using `CLLocation` to get the current location as follows:

```
-(void)loadCurrentLocation{
if (manager==nil) {
    manager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
}

manager.delegate=self;
manager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[manager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self loadCurrentLocation];

 }
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
CLLocation *loc=newLocation;
if (loc!=nil) {
    self.latitude=loc.coordinate.latitude; //1
    self.longitude=loc.coordinate.longitude; //2
    NSLog(@"Gained Latitude:%.f",self.latitude);
    NSLog(@"Gained Longitude:%.f",self.longitude);
}
```

}

Given that `latitude` and `longitude` are declared as follows in the `.h` file:

```
@interface Prayers :UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property double longitude;
@property double latitude;
@end
```

the problem is that the returned values at lines 1 & 2 are integers like 30 and 31 and i was expecting them like `31.377033600000004000` and `30.016893900000000000`, so why the returned values are integers instead of double ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the types weren't what you expect, Xcode would likely be giving you conversion warnings. What makes you think they aren't doubles you are getting back?  Maybe the framework is just rounding to the nearest degree and returning that as a double?

Another possibility. what if your log looked like

```
NSLog(@"Gained Latitude:%.2f",self.latitude);
```

Does that print more accuracy (note, the 2 in the format).

---

Maybe even trying boxing them as an NSNumber and see what that prints:

```
    NSLog(@"Gained Latitude:%@", @(self.latitude));
```